# Ubuntu: `debdelta-upgrade` only upgrades one delta at a time

Tags: debian, ubuntu, python, debdelta

With plain *Debian* [**`debdelta-upgrade`**](http://debdelta.debian.net/) works correctly:  it gets a list of upgradeable files, downloads *all* available deltas, and creates the desired *.deb* upgrade files.  So if packages *foo*, *bar*, and *baz* have available deltas, then `debdelta-upgrade` will fetch *foo*, *bar*, and *baz*, then quit.

But under *Ubuntu* distros, (tested with *Mint* and *Lubuntu*), when there are several packages with available deltas, `debdelta-upgrade` fetches only one delta at a time.  If run once it fetches *foo*, then quits; if run again it fetches *bar*; if run again, it fetches *baz*.

Under *Ubuntu*, this kludge works; it fetches all available deltas, by running `debdelta-upgrade` once for each upgradable package:

```
apt list --upgradable 2> /dev/null | sed -n '1!s#/.*##p' | \
    xargs -n 1 debdelta-upgrade
```

But it's much slower than *Debian*, since each time `debdelta-upgrade` runs it needs 5 seconds or so to initialize ("*updating apt cache*") -- if 10 packages need upgrading, that's an added 50 second delay (*5 seconds x 10 packages*) under *Ubuntu* variants.

Is there a fix?

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem that keeps bugging me, and this is the only post I can find on the interwebs that queries this issue.

I'm not sure it's working at all. *Debdelta* is checking which section it's in (main, backports or stable-security), and using a separate *debdeltas.debian.net* URI for each section.

The script is failing at the line:

```
  delta_uri_base=delta_uri_from_config(config,
                                       Origin=origin.origin,
                                       Label=origin.label,
                                       Site=origin.site,
                                       Archive=origin.archive,
                                       PackageName=p.name)
```

...this is because `delta_uri_base` returns *none* in Ubuntu.

`delta_uri_from_config` appears to be parsing */etc/debdelta/sources.conf* which contains lots of Debian specific entries for the Debian archives - and no relevant sections for Ubuntu.

So, for example we find that the origin it is looking for is:

```
    origin.origin : 
    origin.site:gb.archive.ubuntu.com
    origin.label :Ubuntu
    origin.archive: bionic-updates
```

Looking at the */etc/debdelta/sources.conf*:

```
   [main debian archive]
   Origin=Debian
   Label=Debian
   delta_uri=http://debdeltas.debian.net/debian-deltas

   [backports debian archive]
   Origin=Debian Backports
   Label=Debian Backports
   delta_uri=http://debdeltas.debian.net/debian-deltas


   [stable security debian archive]
   Origin=Debian
   Label=Debian-Security
   delta_uri=http://debdeltas.debian.net/debian-security-deltas
```

There are no sections that match. With no corresponding entry, there is no URI to get the delta from. This means that the delta-queue for upgrades does not get filled, and so it won't loop through to generate deltas for each one.

What's not clear to me at the moment, is why it generates a single *.deb* in */var/cache/apt/archives/* at all.

As far as I can see, to fix it, someone needs to host an Ubuntu specific `debdelta` instance, and correct the sources file. It looks like long ago, someone [tried this](https://ubuntu-in.narkive.com/O53K09NW/experimental-debdelta-repository), but I've not heard of anyone doing this.